# Can the python client tcp socket be used for multiple sends?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I tried using a socket for 2 sends. The first one succeeds and the next one does not.
From the http://docs.python.org/howto/sockets.html
it would appear that multiple sends should be allowed. For Better or worse, I don't really need to read from the socket.
I have used twisted, but for the present purpose, I would like to stick to a socket, if I can help it(partly because I am using it within an application already using twisted to communicate.. this is a seperate connection).

"When the connect completes, the socket s can be used to send in a request for the text of the page. The same socket will read the reply, and then be destroyed. That’s right, destroyed. Client sockets are normally only used for one exchange (or a small set of sequential exchanges)."

return value for the send that succeeds = 35
return value for the send that FAILS = 32

code with some minor editing to remove any business logic.

```
self._commandSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)


def sendPrereqs(self,id,prereqs):
    self._commandSock.connect(self._commandConnection)
    #parse prereqs
    temp = prereqs.split(',')
    for pair in temp:
        tup = pair.partition(':')
        try:
            command = 'some command'
            logging.info('sending command: ' + command)
            ret = self._commandSock.send(command)
            if ret == None:
                logging.info('send called successfully: ' + command)
            else:
                logging.info('socket returned non-None: ' + str(ret))
        except:

            print 'Unexpected Exception ', sys.exc_info()[0]()
            print sys.exc_info()
            #logging.info('Unexpected Exception '+ str(sys.exc_info()[0]()))
            #logging.info(' ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
    self._commandSock.close()`
```

Comment: Please show us the code. And the error message.

Comment: The part you cite is misleading; it applies to HTTP specifically. When a TCP socket is or isn't closed depends entirely on the protocol that's being used on top of it.

Comment: The quote is just refering to how client sockets are used by web browsers, not to the only way client sockets can be used. It _is_ a bit misleading; maybe you want to file a documentation bug?

Comment: One quick guess: Did you `setblocking` or `settimeout` on the socket, and then your second `send` raised an exception? Or, did you do neither, and your second `send` seems to block forever? If so, the answer is that you need a reactor or proactor (whether a trivial `select.select` loop taken right from the doc example, or a full-blown twisted app).

Comment: You _still_ haven't told us what you mean by "FAILS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> return value for the send that succeeds = 35 return value for the send that FAILS = 32
>
> Documentation says that successful send should return None.

No it doesn't. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) says:

> **Returns the number of bytes sent.** Applications are responsible for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the remaining data. For further information on this concept, consult the Socket Programming HOWTO.

You still haven't explained what you mean by "FAILS". The `send` call is returning successfully, and it's almost certainly placed 32 bytes into the socket write buffer.

If the only reason you think it's failing is that it returns the correct value, then the answer is obviously that it's not failing.

If something else is going wrong, there are all kinds of things that could be wrong at a higher level. One likely one is this: The server (especially if it was coded by someone who doesn't understand sockets well) is coded to expect one `recv()` of 35 bytes, and one `recv()` of 32 bytes. But it's actually getting a single `recv()` of 67 bytes, and waiting forever for the second, which never comes. There is no rule guaranteeing that each `send()` on a stream (TCP) socket corresponds to one `recv()` on the other side. You need to create some kind of stream protocol that demarcates the separate messages.

Meanwhile, the quote you're referring to is irrelevant. It's describing how client sockets are used by simple web browsers: They make a connection, do one send, receive all the data, then destroy the connection. I can see why it misled you, and you may want to file a documentation bug to get it improved. But for now, just ignore it.

If you want to make absolutely sure that the client is sending the right data, and the problem is in the server, there are two easy ways to do that:

1. Use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) as a trivial substitute server (e.g., `nc -kl 6000`, replacing the "6000" with the actual port) and making sure it logs what you think the server should be seeing.
2. Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to watch the connection between the client and server.

Once you've verified that the problem is on the server side, you need to debug the server. If you need help with that, that's probably best done in a new question, where you can post the server code instead of the client, and explain (with a link here) that you're sure the client is sending the right information.

Comment: I don't see the second message being recieved on the server.

Comment: I will look into whether , thats whats happening(ie: the server is unable to distinguish between the 2), definitely a possibility.

Comment: There are lots of other possibilities. For example, maybe the server has an improperly-coded `select` loop, so it never comes back to do a second `read`. But now you're trying to debug the server, so if you want help there, we need the server code (and possibly a new question).

Comment: I still don't know what the problem is , but the orginal premise of my question was flawed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is only referring to a common scenario. You can call [`send`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send), [`sendall`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendall), and [`sendto`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) on all sockets as often as you want - as long as the socket is not closed.

Note that these methods return the number of bytes sent, 32 and 35 simply mean you sent 32 bytes the first and 35 bytes the second time.

The fact that `socket.send` returns without an exception means that the data got handed to the operating system, but not that it actually reached the endpoint (or has been read correctly by an application there).

Comment: This is not even wrong… Both TCP and UDP sockets can be used to call `send` as many times as you want. Both are destroyed once closed.

Comment: @abarnert clarified what I meant. You're right, `close` is jumping a step ahead and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: But it's still not true or useful. Both sockets can do an arbitrary number of `send` calls.

Comment: @abarnert Umm, where does this answer say that that is not possible?

Comment: Well, it _did_ say that before 3 further edits completely changed it into a different answer. But it still talks about sending data to another endpoint, which is still almost certainly irrelevant to the OP's problem. And, while we don't know exactly what his problem is, I can't imagine any problem that would be helped by your answer.

Comment: @abarnert I can't find any mention of being able to call `send` a limited number of times in [the original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/3eadb933-5cb8-4a8e-a2e5-5ada93e5f8ed/view-source). The OP asks about limits to sending data on a socket, and I do believe that it's important to note that while you can call `send*` an unlimited number of times, you need multiple sockets if you want to establish TCP connections to multiple endpoints.

Comment: The question was "Can I send multiple times". Your original answer was "It depends on the socket type", and goes on to explain the difference between UDP and TCP, which very strongly implies that the answer is "no for TCP, yes for UDP".

Comment: @abarnert Well, you're reinterpreting quite a bit into the answer. For TCP, it states `(..) send data to one endpoint` as the limitation. Nevertheless, I see that it's easy to misunderstand the old version; that's why I have edited it. The current version should clearly answer the question, but you're welcome to offer improvements.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, let me keep looking. I found it odd , that a socket should be allowed only one send.

Comment: There are only two ways to interpret it: as completely irrelevant to the question (which is probably what you intended), or as completely wrong (which is what I feared the OP would get out of it). Either way, none of the early versions were at all useful. By now, it's a completely different answer.

Comment: @abarnert No offense, but you're coming off as overly aggressive. Why would I intend to write something irrelevant to the question?

Comment: I don't think you actually intended to write something irrelevant to the question; rather, you just wanted to write _an answer_, even though you didn't actually know how to help the OP, and what came out was irrelevant. You seem to have become emotionally attached to your answer, taking any criticism—even of an old version that you yourself said was irrelevant—as a personal attack. Why is it so important to you to have an answer to this question?

Comment: I don't take any criticism as a personal attack, but I misunderstood `completely irrelevant to the question (which is probably what you intended)` as the attempt of one. It's not important for me to have an answer to this question, I just think that it still contains some information missing in your great answer (namely, that a returning `send` means the OS took custody of the data), and is shorter.